# VS Code - search results - open in editor - edit inline

Tags: visual-studio-code

When searching in VS Code I use option "Open in editor" which opens search results in edit tab. The only thing I miss is editing directly in this tab. Double click takes you to the particular file and you can edit there, but editing inline would ease things up.

Is there any option how to edit inline in search results editor tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the context menu and select `Peek`

The keybinding is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: thanks, but it does not do what I want. If I edit it there and press CTRL+S for save it does not save the file the result is in, but it tries to save the file with search results. I need to save the original file. My case is that I edit the occurence of some text in multiple files and would like to save the original files directly from search results edit tab.

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy Just edit the Peek window and escape the Peek Window, the file is modified

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you are asking with this extension:  [search-editor-apply-changes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakearl.search-editor-apply-changes) written by the vscode team member primarily responsible for the search editor functionality.

See, e.g., https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93031:  you can use the Find widget and select its results too to perform a replace and then apply those changes for example or simply edit in place.

When you make changes in your search editor and trigger the extension those changes are made to all the affected files.  Demo:

[image: apply search editor changes]

The command is `searchEditorApplyChanges.apply` which could be bound to your own keybinding.